# Like per page not displaying correct URL on profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am using facebook like social plugin as follows.

```
<fb:like send="true" width="320" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

If there is no href defined, this is said to be pick the current page.

I have a news website and I just want to integrate this like plugin per page, and when someone like a specific news page, i want that to be displayed in user profile.

However this is not the case right now.

I have debug it with firebug and it s getting/sending correct URL to facebook but on facebook profile, i dont see that URL that was liked.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don’t you just put the actual URL into the href attribute of fb:like …?